# Using haproxy to forward or redirect a URL

Tags: redirect, haproxy

I am looking to perform something quite simple.

Using haproxy I would like to forward any requests from the URL http://webmail.rutest.org or https://webmail.rutest.org to https://outlook.com/rutest.org

BASICALLY:
We currently own the domain rutest.org.  What I intend to do is create a DNS "A" record for "webmail" IP address 24.103.122.18.  This will then go to a FortiGate Router which has 2 port forwarding rules for 80 and 443 to an internal IP address 10.1.1.18.  10.1.1.18 will be the haproxy server.  Once that request gets there, I want haproxy to say ok, you want http://webmail.rockefeller.edu or https://webmail.rockefeller.edu then send the user to https://outlook.com/rutest.org

The users browser should then reflect this URL redirection.

Can this be done?  If so, what are the entries needed in the haproxy.cfg?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, untested.

```
listen webmail
  bind :80 v4v6
                                        # here should be your certificates
  bind :::443 v4v6 alpn h2,http/1.1 ssl crt /etc/ssl/haproxy/
  
  http-request redirect location https://outlook.com/rutest.org if hdr(host) -i webmail.rockefeller.edu
```

The documentation: [http-request redirect](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.3/configuration.html#4.2-http-request%20redirect)